# Does this operator equation have solutions?

Tags: operator-theory

Hi Math StackExchange community,

I have a question that originates from a Physics problem; the question itself however is about solving an operator equation. In a particular quantum mechanical setting, I investigate the action of the time reversal operator (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/T-symmetry), $\mathcal{T}$. The time reversal operator is anti-linear. My problem reduces to solving the operator equation:

$$(1)  \phantom{texttexttext}\mathcal{T} =e^{\mathcal{Q}},\phantom{texttexttexttest}$$

where the **unknown** is $\mathcal{Q}\equiv\mathcal{Q}(\hat{x},\hat{p})$ which is self-adjoint and depends on the position and momentum operators $\hat{x}$ (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Position_operator) and $\hat{p}$ (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Momentum_operator), respectively. Both $\hat{x}$ and $\hat{p}$ are linear operators.

I want to argue that equation (1) is inconsistent, i.e. that it is not possible to find such a $\mathcal{Q}$. However, I am unsure about one major step. For which properties of $\mathcal{Q}$ is the following statement (I) true? Does it need to be analytic? Is there some simple counter-example that you can think of where (I) does not hold?

(I) *Given that $\hat{x}$, $\hat{p}$ are linear operators, then $\mathcal{Q}(\hat{x},\hat{p})$ is also a linear operator.*

N.B.: If $\mathcal{Q}$ is analytic, (I) clearly holds since it will be a series in powers of $\hat{x}^i\hat{p}^j$ which is linear since each term is linear individually.

I hope to be able to argue (I) since then it would follow that,

Corollary of (I): *The operator exponential $e^\mathcal{Q}$ results in a linear operator.*

This however means that we would have "anti-linear operator = linear operator", which is a contradiction. Thus, (1) would not have a solution for $\mathcal{Q}$.

Thank you for your help in advance.

Comment: I don't think I've ever seen someone use `\phantom` the way you did in your display for $(1)$. +1 for bizarre usage

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A self-adjoint operator, as part of its definition, is a linear operator.  The exponential of a self-adjoint operator, as defined e.g. by the functional calculus (see Spectral Theorem), is again a linear operator.  The only linear operator that is also anti-linear is the $0$ operator (which can't be the exponential of a linear operator).

Comment: You start out saying that by definition, a self-adjoint operator is linear. However, one can also define a Hermitian adjoint for anti-linear operators, c.f. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hermitian_adjoint#Adjoints_of_antilinear_operators. Thus I wonder why the definition of self-adjointness is restricted to linear operators as you say. Is it because only for the adjoint of a linear operator, all the nice results like the Spectral Theorem hold?

Comment: I don't know if it's because of a "linear bias", but I don't think anti-linear operators are studied very much, certainly a lot less than linear operators.  Of course, they are in one-to-one correspondence with the linear operators, in the sense that given an anti-linear involution $J$, $A$ is anti-linear iff $JA$ is linear.  But the algebra is somewhat different.  I don't know  what an anti-linear Spectral Theorem would look like.